# pyinstaller generated exe file that uses Theano lib, doesn't run in anaconda environment with python 2

Tags: python, anaconda, theano, pyinstaller

I've generated an .exe file with pyinstaller.
I took the folder with all the dependencies and the .exe file to another computer that has anaconda with python2.
I drag and dropped the .exe file into a command line and executed it. An error was thrown "Cannot import theano.something". I don't have the exact error, but it had to do with Theano that is python 3.4+.
Since I didn't open an anaconda shell, could the anaconda configuration mess up with the execution of this .exe file? Shouldn't the .exe file find it's dependencies independently of the anaconda installation?

It should be noted that the same .exe file was ran successfully in 5 computers and one of them had anaconda with python3 while the others didn't have anaconda at all.

Comment: I haven't worked with theano. But one instance got me an application build with pyinstaller where I had to specify the submodules manually in hidden import parameters. Trying that might help.

Comment: were any warnings generated when you compiled with PyInstaller?